# Application interface font style italic

Tags: fonts, menu, interface, android-studio, intellij

In some applications, like Android Studio, the whole interface font (the one of the menus and so on) is entirely in italic. In IntelliJ on the hand, this is not the case.

I did not change any settings of the application - the interface font of both Android Studio and Intellij is set to the exact same font.

The only thing that works is completely deleting the .otf file for the italic style of the font, but this is not really a solution as it is then missing for cases where it actually is needed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Would you mind to let us know which font it is?

Comment: The font is SF Pro Display by Apple

Comment: In that case it would be good if you show exactly which files related to that font you have on your system and in which folders. Please edit your question and add that info there.